# Multiple live streaming from VLC to website

Tags: php, streaming, vlc

look at this article: http://wiki.videolan.org/Stream_VLC_to_Website_with_asf_and_Flash I was able to capture video and flow, but the problem is it works as point to point.
I need a php code which, for example, captures the code, saves according to IP address, and site can flow it to SWF. But I dont know how to do it. This could be the way at all? If I just save the stream, the spectators could only watch it from the beginning, not in the "red hand". The flash player only eats files. How to make it live?

Comment: You need a server to relay the stream.  What formats and codecs are you using?  How many users do you predict you will need to be streaming to?

Comment: server is available already. I just dont know what to do with the incoming stuffs. Codec is WMV2, and Windows WMV/asf